Challenges with oversampling in multi-label classification for non-image small datasets
I'm developing a multi-label classification model with a small dataset of 900 rows, not involving images. It's similar to a tag classification problem, where I have 12 output columns (tags) that can each be 0 or 1. Some columns have the value 1 occurring less than 4% of the time.
I'm exploring oversampling methods to address this imbalance and came across the MLSMOTE technique. However, it hasn't been effective with my data. Has anyone else faced this issue? I've tried using several scikit-multilearn libraries, but none offer oversampling solutions. Additionally, the imblearn library does not support multi-label classification directly. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thank you!
